# How can I iterate over a list of logical predicates?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

**UPDATE**: The following question may be a common beginner's not-to-follow approach when attempting to program custom functions comprising some `dplyr` operations. In these cases, tt may be about time to learn the concept of non-standard evaluation and best practices: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

---

I am trying to map over a data set to replace several values. Given that I want to do it several times, is it possible (or a good idea) crease a list with the specified logical predicates and then `purrr::map` them?

For example, in the `starwars` dataset, if I wanted to replace `skin_color` values meeting certain criteria, I could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> -- Attaching packages -------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
#> v ggplot2 2.2.1.9000     v purrr   0.2.4     
#> v tibble  1.4.2          v dplyr   0.7.4     
#> v tidyr   0.7.2          v stringr 1.2.0     
#> v readr   1.1.1          v forcats 0.2.0
#> -- Conflicts ----------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() --
#> x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

replaced_starwars <- starwars %>% 
  mutate(skin_color = replace(skin_color, (hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black"), 
                              "SOMETHING_HERE"))

head(filter(replaced_starwars, hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black"), 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 13
#>   name    height  mass hair_color skin_color   eye_color birth_year gender
#>   <chr>    <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>        <chr>          <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 Nien N~    160  68.0 none       SOMETHING_H~ black           NA   male  
#> 2 Gasgano    122  NA   none       SOMETHING_H~ black           NA   male  
#> 3 Kit Fi~    196  87.0 none       SOMETHING_H~ black           NA   male  
#> 4 Plo Ko~    188  80.0 none       SOMETHING_H~ black           22.0 male  
#> 5 Lama Su    229  88.0 none       SOMETHING_H~ black           NA   male  
#> # ... with 5 more variables: homeworld <chr>, species <chr>, films <list>,
#> #   vehicles <list>, starships <list>
```

How can I store logical predicates in a list, and map them thereafter with `my_function`?

```r
my_function <- function(my_data, lgc_predicates, replacement){
  out <- my_data %>% mutate(species = replace(species, lgc_predicates, replacement))
  return(out)
}

pred_list <- list('hair_color == "blond" & eye_color == "yellow"',
                  'hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "brown"',
                  'hair_color == "brown" & eye_color == "red"',
                  'hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black"')

replaced_starwars <- map(starwars, 
                     my_function, 
                     lgc_predicates = pred_list, replacement = "SOMETHING_HERE")
#> Error in UseMethod("mutate_"): no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Comment: What output are you looking to have? Is a list sufficient?

Comment: in the example, I wan to have a new `starwars` (e.g. `replaced_starwars`) dataframe with the `skin_color` values replaced with the replacement.

Comment: the way you map looks strange. It sounds like you would want to map a function to your `pred_list` and have the dataset (`starwars`) as an additional argument to your custom function. you might want to swap the arguments in `my_function` and the call to `map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I like `dplyr::case_when` in this situation

```
output <- starwars %>%
            mutate(skin_color = case_when(
                hair_color == "blond" & eye_color == "yellow" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "brown" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                hair_color == "brown" & eye_color == "red" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                TRUE ~ skin_color))

head(filter(output, hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black"), 5)

# A tibble: 5 x 13
  # name  heig~  mass hair~ skin~ eye_~ birt~ gend~ home~ spec~ films vehi~ star~
  # <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lis> <lis> <lis>
# 1 Nien~   160  68.0 none  SOME~ black  NA   male  Sull~ Sull~ <chr~ <chr~ <chr~
# 2 Gasg~   122  NA   none  SOME~ black  NA   male  Troi~ Xexto <chr~ <chr~ <chr~
# 3 Kit ~   196  87.0 none  SOME~ black  NA   male  Glee~ Naut~ <chr~ <chr~ <chr~
# 4 Plo ~   188  80.0 none  SOME~ black  22.0 male  Dorin Kel ~ <chr~ <chr~ <chr~
# 5 Lama~   229  88.0 none  SOME~ black  NA   male  Kami~ Kami~ <chr~ <chr~ <chr~
```

You can even pass a list of arguments but you have to unquote both the list and the column names as such:

```
pred_list <- list(!! hair_color == "blond" & !! eye_color == "yellow" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                  !! hair_color == "none" & !! eye_color == "brown" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                  !! hair_color == "brown" & !! eye_color == "red" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                  !! hair_color == "none" & !! eye_color == "black" ~ "SOMETHING_HERE",
                  TRUE ~ !! skin_color)

output <- starwars %>%
        mutate(skin_color = case_when(!!! pred_list))
```